# Publishing C# application to other devices - program won't open

Tags: c#, ms-access, publish

I have created a program in C# and have published it using (Visual Studio) Build > Publish Project, then select file path etc..

I have decided to let the users download this program using a dropbox link that I provide them, however when they download this link and go to open the program once it has been installed, It will come up with a box that says 'Launching Application' for a very short time, then this dissapears and nothing else happens - the program doesn't open!

Is this an issue with the type of file that it is? (.application)

Comment: have you installed .net framework in the other device?

Comment: Yes it has been installed on the other device, I was thinking about creating a setup.exe file and sharing this but visual studio seems to be missing their own installer